# Sync Windows Briefcase Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows

Does anyone know how I would go about forcing windows to synchronize every file in a briefcase? Preferably in c#.

Or, if that is not possible, is it possible to read in the files (and linked files) in the briefcase, then copy them?

Comment: What do you define as a briefcase? A folder?

Comment: I think it basically is a folder, but windows will sync all of the files in it with a destination. But it will only do it when a button is clicked, not automatically. I am trying to make it happen automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes - Details here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and listen for the change events. Then you can use something like the Sync Framework, your own version, other open source to sync the data.

Comment: The file system watcher looks like it will do the trick, then I can just have the modified files copied to their rightful places. Thank you.

Comment: Yep you jsut have to Wire into the events and let Windows do the rest. Then your logic can do the actual syncing.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Microsoft's Sync Framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx

This section describes synchronizing files, along with some code samples in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902860.aspx